# Abstract algebra: Normal subgroup problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I got stuck on this specific problem:

> Let $G$ be a group and $H \mathrel{\unlhd} G$ with $|G : H| = p^k$ with $p$ is a prime and $ k \geq 1$.
>
> Prove that there exists a $g \in G$ such that $g \not\in H, g^2 \not\in H, g^3 \not\in H, ... g^{p-1} \not\in H$ but $g^p \in H$.

So we know that there are $p^k$ cosets and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ ($gH = Hg, \forall g \in G$).

From here, I have no idea how to find that such $g$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Often when you have a normal subgroup, it is helpful to look at the quotient group.  What do you know about $G/H$ in this case?

Comment: So, G/H is the set of all left/right cosets and $|G/H| = p^k$? I'm sorry but some more hints could help

Comment: The important thing is that $G/H$ is also a group.  If a group has order $p^k$, what do you know about the orders of the elements in that group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

$H \mathrel{\unlhd} G, \tag 1$

the collection of (left or right) cosets of $H$ form a group $G/H$; the order of this group is the index $[G:H]$ of $H$ in $G$; thus

$\vert G/H \vert = [G:H] = p^k, k \ge 1; \tag 2$

thus

$p \mid \vert G/H \vert, \tag 3$

and hence it follows from [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) that $G/H$ contains an element of order $p$; such an element of $G/H$ is then a coset of the form $gH$ for some $g \in G$, and since

$\vert gH \vert = p, \tag 4$

it follows that

$(gH)^k \ne e_{G/H}, \; 1 \le k \le p - 1, \; (gH)^p = e_{G/H}, \tag 5$

where $e_{G/H}$ denotes the identity element of the group $G/H$, that is, the coset
$eH$ where $e$ is the identity element of $G$.  Now

$(gH)^k = g^kH, \tag 6$

and

$g^kH = e_{G/H} \Longleftrightarrow g^k \in H; \tag 7$

it follows then that

$g^k \notin H, \; 1 \le k \le p - 1, \; g^p \in H, \tag 8$

which was to be proved.

Comment: This makes sense to me. Thank you so much, sir.

Comment: @ThaiDoan:  my pleausre.  And thanks for the "acceptance"!